# how to insert multiple images into collection with multiple upload buttons using wix velo code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to coding. I have a Registration Form in Editor X "RegistrationForm" and in it I have multiple upload buttons which need to be used by applicants to upload their Recent Photo, National Identification Number, O'Level Certificate, A'Level Certificate and University Certificate.

I can write the code for uploading photos into Wix Collections but I can't insert the images into the same row of the collection.

I need to upload the 5 images into the same row of the collection. The Registration Form has about 20 input fields along with the 5 image and document upload buttons. I want to insert the images and documents into the same row as the other 20 input values.

Comment: You want to show images after upload or show a preview before upload?

Comment: If is a preview, you can set the "src" value of the image tag with the url for the file selected "URL.createObjectURL" can help you with this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Also, wix velo have a way to do this with their own library: https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-tutorial-using-the-upload-button-with-code?_gl=1*qaqs7*_ga*MTkxNTE4Mjk2Mi4xNjUyOTI4Njg1*_ga_H314XQHSPY*MTY1MjkyODY4NS4xLjAuMTY1MjkyODY4Ny41OA..

Comment: Hey @Elvis Pimentel, thanks for getting back so quickly. No I don't need to preview the image. I just need to upload the 5 images into the same row of the collection. The Registration Form has about 20 input fields along with the 5 image and document upload buttons. I want to insert the images and documents into the same row as the other 20 input values.